# ADE extension associated with Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: ms-access-2016, ms-access-2000

We (still) have an Microsoft Access 2000 application, installed at our customers as an ADE-file (compiled from ADP). It runs in the Microsoft Access 2000 runtime. However, every now and then the ADE-files are associated with Microsoft Access 2016, and when we run the ADE-file, it is opened in Access 2016. Then an error message appears saying that these projects are not supported by Access 2016. This can only be fixed temporarily by repairing the Access 2000 runtime setup.

Even if we run our application by including the path to Access 2000 in the batchfile, the ADE is opened in Access 2016.

I'm looking for a solution where the ADE-file association is fixed (if necessary) everytime our customer starts our application. Basically I want to know what happens when the Office 2000 setup is repaired.

Comment: What happens if you use a _Shortcut_, specify the full path to the runtime - with the ADP file as parameter - and specify "Start in" to the folder of the runtime?

Comment: I cannot try this right now as the problem is not at hand. However I created a batchfile at our customer with a complete path to the Access 2000 runtime executable and a parameter to our ADE-file, and it still tried to open the ADE in Access 2016 after the ADE extension assoctiation was changed to Access 2016. When the association was OK the batchfile worked as intended.